# Jersey JAX-RS auto-generated webservices and MSSQL Identity fields

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, netbeans, jersey

I can't get working the Jersey RESTful webservices, autogenerated with Netbeans.

When POSTing the JSON like this,

```
{"name":"Some New Site"}
```

the POST query returns me this,

```
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert
explicit value for identity column in table 'site' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
Error Code: 544
Call: INSERT INTO site (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind =&gt; [2 parameters bound]
```

Unlike MySQL, MSSQL doesn't generate new autoincremented ID when the NULL value is passed in INSERT query; it needs the ID field not to mentioned at all to generate value for it.

(IDENTITY_INSERT will not make ID to be generated either)

**How do I teach my Jersey services to omit the id field in INSERT query?**

**edit:** here's the POJO, it was generated automatically for me by Netbeans with it's "Restful Web Services From Database" wizard. (I am trying to be as little original as possible)

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ru.fedd.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author fkravchenko
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "site")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Site.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Site s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Site.findById", query = "SELECT s FROM Site s WHERE s.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Site.findByName", query = "SELECT s FROM Site s WHERE s.name = :name")})
public class Site implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "siteId")
    private Collection<Document> documentCollection;

    public Site() {
    }

    public Site(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Site(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Document> getDocumentCollection() {
        return documentCollection;
    }

    public void setDocumentCollection(Collection<Document> documentCollection) {
        this.documentCollection = documentCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Site)) {
            return false;
        }
        Site other = (Site) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ru.fedd.entities.Site[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share your POJO class here?

You probably have to annotate your id of the POJO class with @GeneratedValue to notify it is auto generated. Then JPA will take care of the insertion.

Comment: have no access to this project right now since we have big holidays here, will check soon, thank you!

Comment: when adding @GeneratedValue, i shurely moved further, but it says now

`Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?` ... `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'SEQUENCE'.'`

Comment: `@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)` helped! thanks a lot! maybe update your answer?

Comment: Strategy is depended on projects. so I will leave it like that